# Python: filter lines based on field match from another file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have generated a list with my other python code, which looks like this. there are lines separated by commas and they are in single quotes. I am trying hard to filter the lines based on `D:` column match from another file, which has only starting number characters.

```
data = ['A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+18700000, E:+12355, F:ROOT', 'A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+22211111, E:+12355, F:ROOT', 'A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+177232, E:+12355', 'A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+368399793, E:+12355']
```

it looks likes this line by line in single quotes.

```
[
'A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+18700000, E:+12355, F:ROOT', 
'A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+22211111, E:+12355, F:ROOT', 
'A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+177232, E:+12355', 
'A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+368399793, E:+12355'
]
```

I have another file which has filtering numbers, to be matched in above lists/

```
cat fields.txt
+36
+18
#these are country prefixes
```

I need to match above lists D: column to "fields.txt" file starting numbers and print only those lines. Since "data" `D:` col numbers vary every time, I need to filter based on their country prefix.

output expected:

```
[
'A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+18700000, E:+12355, F:ROOT', ###matched as starting num +18 in D: col
'A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+368399793, E:+12355'  ###matched as starting num +36 in D: col
]
```

I have already tried various examples to write a "FOR" loop and match the nums but no luck.

please help me. I am new to Python programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is need to split each item in the data list
You can simply do

```
data = [
'A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+18700000, E:+12355, F:ROOT', 
'A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+22211111, E:+12355, F:ROOT', 
'A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+177232, E:+12355', 
'A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+368399793, E:+12355'
]

with open("fields.txt") as f:
    codes = f.read().splitlines()

required = []
for item in data:
    for code in codes:
        if "D:%s" %code in item:
            required.append(item)
print(required)
```

You will end up with

```
[
'A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+18700000, E:+12355, F:ROOT',
'A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+368399793, E:+12355'
]
```

Comment: thanks dennohpeter. it helps and exactly fits my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) with an included `if` condition. This has the benefit that your logic which decides which line to include or exclude can be nicely tucked away in a separate function (`matches` in  the example below).

Having a separate function makes this very testable, you can add a docstring and it makes it much more maintainable.

```
data = [
    "A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+18700000, E:+12355, F:ROOT",
    "A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+22211111, E:+12355, F:ROOT",
    "A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+177232, E:+12355",
    "A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+368399793, E:+12355",
]


def load_codes():
    with open("fields.txt") as fieldfile:
        codes = fieldfile.read().splitlines()
    return codes


def matches(row, codes):
    for code in codes:
        if "D:%s" % code in row:
            return True
    return False


def main():
    codes = load_codes()
    filtered = [row for row in data if matches(row, codes)]

    for row in filtered:
        print(row)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this solution suits your need:

```
with open("fields.txt") as f:
    codes = f.read().splitlines()

data = ['A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+18700000, E:+12355, F:ROOT', \
        'A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+22211111, E:+12355, F:ROOT', \
        'A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+177232, E:+12355', \
        'A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+368399793, E:+12355']

for index, item in enumerate(data):
    sub_items =item.replace(" ", "").split(",")  # to remove spaces and get each individual item
    for sub_item in sub_items: # you can replace this for loop with sub_items[3] if the position of D: is fixed
        if(sub_item.startswith("D:")):
            value = sub_item.replace("D:", "")  # here you have +xxxx in the data point
            # you can apply the logic here:
            for code in codes:
                if value.startswith(code):
                    print(code, value, index, data[index])
```

It prints the following lines if `fields.txt` contains the numbers you mentioned in the question:

```
+18 +18700000 0 A:SET, B:FW.O, C:AS, D:+18700000, E:+12355, F:ROOT
+36 +368399793 3 A:SET, B:IT, C:AS, D:+368399793, E:+12355
```

Comment: thanks a lot.. it suits my requirement, but i preferred to use other method though i am not really sure which is best method.. THANKS AGAIN.